Error: 9 FAILED_PRECONDITION received for Firebase Function
I have a function where a learner is added to a programme which creates a learnerProgrammeJunction document which then triggers the function addLearnerModuleJunction which essentially adds the learner to all the modules within the programme by creating learnerModuleJunction documents to associate the learner between each module. The learnerModuleJunction function has stopped working and we have been receiving an error.
Below is the code:
exports.addLearnerModuleJunction = functions.firestore.document('learnerProgrammesJunction/{docID}').onCreate(async (snap, context) => {

    const learnerProgrammeData = snap.data();

    // run through each module in the programme

    const modules = await db.collection('projects').doc(learnerProgrammeData.project_uid).collection('modules').where('programme_uid', '==', learnerProgrammeData.programme_uid).get();



        await Promise.all(modules.docs.map(async (module) => {
        const moduleData = module.data();
        console.log(moduleData.module_name);
        // console.log(moduleData.uid);
        // console.log(learnerProgrammeData.learner_uid);
        const learnerModuleJunction = await db.collection('learnerModulesJunction').where('learner_uid' , '==', learnerProgrammeData.learner_uid).where('module_uid', '==', module.id).get();

        // console.log(learnerModuleJunction);
        // rest of your code here
        if (learnerModuleJunction.empty) {
            console.log('in');

            const learnerModuleData = {
                programme_uid: learnerProgrammeData.programme_uid,
                learner_uid: learnerProgrammeData.learner_uid,
                learner_ref: db.collection('learners').doc(learnerProgrammeData.learner_uid),
                status: 'Assigned',
                com_nyc: false,
                closed: false,
                learner_name: learnerProgrammeData.learner_name,
                learner_id_number: learnerProgrammeData.learner_id_number,
                learner_phone_number: learnerProgrammeData.learner_phone_number,
                module_uid: module.id,
                poe: "Not Submitted",
                project_uid: learnerProgrammeData.project_uid,
                learner_programme_junction_ref: snap.ref,
                learner_programme_junction_uid: context.params.docID,
            };

            // Reference to LearnerProjects subcollection
            const learnerModuleCollection = db.collection(`learnerModulesJunction`);

            // Add document to LearnerProjects subcollection
            learnerModuleCollection.add(learnerModuleData)
                .then((docRef) => {
                    console.log(`LearnerModule document added with ID: ${docRef.id}`);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error('Error adding LearnerModule document:', error);
                });
        }
    }));

The function has stopped working and we have been receiving the below error:
Error: 9 FAILED_PRECONDITION: 
    at callErrorFromStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:19)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:357:73)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:323:181)
    at /workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/resolving-call.js:94:78
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11) 

When researching the above error, most solutions point to indexing and that there should be a link provided to create the new index. When looking at the code, I believe I have manually covered all document collections and collection groups in the indexes, but any suggestions would be welcomed. The modules collection is a collection group and the others are standard collections.
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Use the same JavaScript code in a piece of client-side SDK or a local Node.js script and run it to see the actual error message from it.
